# Gradle CustomTask not considering InputFiles for dependencies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to write a custom Gradle task that takes a specific set of input files, which may be in different directories, an output file and call a javaexec with the inputs.

I currently have it where it will skip the @TaskAction if it sees that the @OutputFile exists but it pays no consideration to the InputFiles list and if they are newer than the output file.

Here are the relevant parts of the buildfile:

```
class JavaCPPTask extends DefaultTask {
   def className = []
   String outputDir = ""
   String localClasspath = "bin/classes"
   String runIfExists = ""
   String javacpp = "libs/javacpp.jar"
   String outputName = ""

   //@InputDirectory
   //File inputFile = new File("bin/classes/com/package/ve")

   @InputFiles
   List<File> getInputFiles() {
      ArrayList<File> inputFiles = new ArrayList<File>()
      for ( int i = 0; i < className.size(); i++ ) {
         def inputFileStr = localClasspath + '/' + className.get(i).replace('.','/') + '.class' 
         println("InputFileStr: " + inputFileStr )
         File inputFile = new File(inputFileStr)
         println("Input file exists? " + inputFile.exists() )
         inputFiles.add(inputFile)
      }
      return inputFiles
   }


   @OutputFile
   File getTargetFile() {
         if ( outputName.length() == 0 ) {
            def nameWithPackage = className.get(0)
            def name = nameWithPackage.substring(nameWithPackage.lastIndexOf(".")+1)
            outputName = 'jni' + name;
         }

         File outputFile = new File( outputDir + outputName + '.cpp');
         println("Output Name is: " + outputFile )
         println("Output file exists? " + outputFile.exists() )
         return outputFile
   }

   JavaCPPTask() {
   }

   @TaskAction
   def javacpp() {

      def haveFile = new File(runIfExists)
      if ( runIfExists.length() > 0 && ! haveFile.exists() ) {
         println("Skipping class " + className + " makefile does not exist: " + runIfExists );
      }
      else {
         def useOutputName = []
         if ( outputName.length() > 0 ) {
            useOutputName = [ '-o', outputName ]
         }
         def optionArray = [ '-nocompile', '-classpath', localClasspath, '-d', outputDir ]
         def allOptions = [javacpp] + useOutputName + optionArray + className.findAll()

         project.javaexec { main="-jar"; args allOptions }  

      }
   }
}

def codecOpus = ['com.package.ve.CodecOpus']

task javaCPP_CodecOpus(type:JavaCPPTask) {
   className = codecOpus
   outputDir = 'jni/VECodecOpus/'
   runIfExists = outputDir + 'Android.mk'
}
```

And the output, which may or may not help.  The output file has already been created by a previous run, but the .class file has been updated so I'd expect that the target would run again.

```
> c:\java\gradle-2.2.1\bin\gradle  -b build

JavaCPP.gradle javaCPP_CodecOpus
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
InputFileStr: bin/classes/com/package/ve/CodecOpus.class
Input file exists? true
:javaCPP_CodecOpus
InputFileStr: bin/classes/com/package/ve/CodecOpus.class
Input file exists? true
Output Name is: jni\VECodecOpus\jniCodecOpus.cpp
Output file exists? true
Output Name is: jni\VECodecOpus\jniCodecOpus.cpp
Output file exists? true
Output Name is: jni\VECodecOpus\jniCodecOpus.cpp
Output file exists? true
Output Name is: jni\VECodecOpus\jniCodecOpus.cpp
Output file exists? true
InputFileStr: bin/classes/com/package/ve/CodecOpus.class
Input file exists? true
:javaCPP_CodecOpus UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out after debugging through the Gradle source, the script is working.  I had been forcing an update and a recompile on the .java file which created a new .class file, but Gradle was smart enough to know that the contents of the class file had not changed.  Once I changed the source in the .java file and recompiled, Gradle correctly identified the source as changed and rebuilt the target.

Guess I've been using Make for far too long.

There's still and issue with the script since i was forced to run a clean build before I started down this rabbit hole, but the out of date input file wasn't it.